# Error running Jest: Interface 'Matchers<R, T>' incorrectly extends interface 'TestingLibraryMatchers<(str: string) => any, R>'

Tags: typescript, jestjs, stenciljs

I am trying to build a Stencil library, but I am getting the following error from Jest.

```
stencil-library:dev: > stencil build --dev --watch --serve
stencil-library:dev:
stencil-library:dev: [09:03.6]  @stencil/core
stencil-library:dev: [09:03.8]  v2.16.1 
stencil-library:dev: [09:06.4]  build, stencil-demo, dev mode, started ...
stencil-library:dev: [09:06.4]  transpile started ...
stencil-library:dev: [09:09.8]  transpile finished in 3.37 s
stencil-library:dev: [09:10.1]  build, stencil-demo, dev mode, started ...
stencil-library:dev: [09:10.1]  transpile started ...
stencil-library:dev: [09:13.4]  transpile finished in 3.23 s
stencil-library:dev:
stencil-library:dev: [ ERROR ]  TypeScript: ../../node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts:691:15
stencil-library:dev:            Interface 'Matchers<R, T>' incorrectly extends interface
stencil-library:dev:            'TestingLibraryMatchers<(str: string) => any, R>'.The types returned
stencil-library:dev:            by 'toHaveAttribute(...)' are incompatible between these types.Type
stencil-library:dev:            'void' is not assignable to type 'R'.'R' could be instantiated with
stencil-library:dev:            an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'void'.
stencil-library:dev:
stencil-library:dev:     L690:  // should be R extends void|Promise<void> but getting dtslint error
stencil-library:dev:     L691:  interface Matchers<R, T = {}> {
stencil-library:dev:     L692:      /**
stencil-library:dev:
stencil-library:dev: [09:13.4]  build failed, watching for changes... in 3.25
```

It appears that Stencil is trying to invoke Jest after transpiling and that's where TypeScript errors out. Any clue what's going on?

My repository is here: https://github.com/nareshbhatia/stencil-demo

To reproduce the error, simply run the following:

```bash
npm install

# Run the stencil-library in the browser (http://localhost:3333)
npm run dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

The issue was narrowed down to a stencil dependency: @stencil/react-output-target. This library has dependencies to older versions of React and React Testing Library:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react": "^16.7.0",
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.7.0",
  "react": "^16.7.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
  "react-testing-library": "^7.0.0"
}
```

I downgraded React from v18 to v17 and dropped react-testing-library completely to make this work.